# Bulk 301 redirect for Taxonomies with pagination

Tags: taxonomy, redirect, pagination, htaccess, seo

I'm looking for the best way to bulk redirect for modified taxonomy URLs.

After category slug has been changed, I need to perform a redirect for all paginated pages:

```
/category-old/       redirects to /category-new/
/category-old/page/2 redirects to /category-new/page/2
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73173943) recommends using an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/category-old/(.*)$ /category-new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works, but I would like to do redirect using a wordpress tools, because it's easier to keep track of all changes and you don't have to write many lines of code in the file and etc.

Maybe there are some plugins where you can set mass redirect for categories, tags and their pagination pages with a some simple setting?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic here since they change over time. If you search through wordpress.org/plugins you should be able to find some options.

Comment: _Aside:_ "This works" - That rule would never work in `.htaccess` because you are trying to match a slash prefix on the URL-path using the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. The regex should read `^category-old/(.*)` instead (no slash after the `^`). The post you linked to has `/?`, which is OK, but unnecessary in `.htaccess`.

Comment: I was surprised that I had to open a topic with this question at all, as it seemed to me that a large number of website developers had encountered this problem and it should have been solved long ago. But, for some reason, I could not find any articles describing redirects specifically for subpages with pagination...